# gitlab-ci Command was not run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I am facing a weird issue using gitlab-ci. My gitlab-ci.yml is unable to process any word containing "prod" like product/production etc. Even a simple CI file as mentioned fails with error "Command was not run". However, it is able to process "Prod"(Uppercase P). My Gitlab runner

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo production
```

I have even Tried assigning it as a CI variable. still, the same issue.
CI Variable "ENV_P=prod"

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $ENV_P
```

[image]

Comment: You mention that it's not possible to echo out words which contain "prod". Is it possible to echo out something else then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with my environment. I was running Gitlab runner on Mac OS. I had installed dotfiles using ansible galaxy `geerlingguy.dotfiles`. It modified my `.bash_profile`. It had a function `prod_command_trap` which was causing the issue. This function was traping any command which was matching `*prod*` and was blocking it. After modifying my `.bash_profile` the CI started to work.

Posting the solution so that it can be useful to others if they face the same issue.